# Requesting root access for android app

Tags: android

I know there are already questions about that here, but I tried all the answers given without success.

There's a simple CheckBoxPreference (titled "Root"):

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="root"
    android:title="@string/root"
    android:summary="@string/root_summary"
    android:defaultValue="false" />
```

Now I need to set the OnPreferenceChangeListener on it and gain root access. If so the checkbox should be checked, otherwise it should not:

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity implements OnPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

        findPreference("root").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        String key = preference.getKey();
        if ("root".equals(key) && !((CheckBoxPreference) preference).isChecked()) {
            try {
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                p.waitFor();
                Log.d("Settings", Integer.toString(p.exitValue()));
                if (p.exitValue() == 255) {
                    Log.d("Settings", "###NO ROOT###");
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Settings", "###NO ROOT###");
                Log.d("Settings", e.getMessage());
                return false;
            }
            Log.d("Settings", "!!!ROOT!!!");
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Superuser prompts correctly for root access. Denying however also returns true, as exitValue is 1 (???) and allowing freezes the whole app (I guess at p.waitFor).

I'm currently running Superuser 3.1.3 with su binary 3.1.1 (newest versions).

Taking a look into logcat I can see the following message: `Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{42c0ebb8 com.example/.gui.Settings}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command you're running is just `su` which will, I suspect, run a shell as superuser. You're waiting (indefinitely) for that shell to finish.

You need to specify `su some-command-here-which-needs-to-run-as-root`.

Unfortunately, there is no way to achieve superuser permissions for the Java code within your Android project. The root-ness applies only to commands which are spawned by `su` itself.

Comment: How does ES File Manager doing this? It's the same procedure: Settings -> Root-Settings -> Root Explorer (which is a CheckBoxPreference). I would like to do the same. Which command does it perform/do I need to perform then?

Comment: I assume it's running individual file operations as root (UNIX commands such as `mv`, `ls`, etc.)

Comment: No, I mean later, when it comes to run the file operations. If the preference for root privileges was 'yes' then it will run them with `su` prepended; otherwise it won't. I haven't used that app so I don't know, but that's what I would expect.

Comment: Sure, but that wasn't my question. What command should I run for my CheckBoxPreference?

Comment: None at all, unless you want something actually to occur as soon as the user checked the preference. You only need to use `su` when you actually want to _do_ something which involves superuser privileges. If I am missing the point, please explain what you want the user to see, or what you want to happen, when the user checks that preference.

Comment: I already did. The user should get a root access prompt which already happens. If user selects allow the preference should be checked, otherwise not. Then on each first call of the main activity it should ask for root access if the preference is checked and overwrite the preference if root access was denied or failed.

Comment: OK, in which case, run `su -c some-command-which-returns-0`, e.g. try `su -c "cat /init.rc"`. It should return more or less immediately, then you can use the exitValue to work out whether it worked.

Comment: Thanks, now it seems to work. Is it correct to check for 0/1 now instead of 255?